# C# xml Doc generator

Tags: c#, xml, document

I have commented all my code up and get the generated xml doc, I was wondering if there is a way to view this nicely on a webpage, like javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which allows to produce documentation in different formats (HTML, CHM, etc).